# Compiling and using Groovy classes from Java at runtime?

Tags: java, groovy, compilation, interpreter

I have an app which I'd like to make extensible by letting users define classes in Groovy, eventually implementing some interfaces.

The key aspect is that it should be interpreted/compiled at runtime. I.e. I need my app to take the `.groovy` and compile it. Doing it during boot is ok.

Then, of course, my app should be able to instantiate that class.

I see two solutions:

1) Compile while the app runs, put the classes somewhere on classpath, and then just load the classes, pretending they were always there.

2) Some smarter way - calling a compiler API and some classloading magic to let my system classloader see them.

**How would I do option 2)?**
**Any other ideas?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at [Integrating Groovy into applications](http://groovy-lang.org/integrating.html)

- Get class Loader
- Load class
- Instantiate class.

*Beauty*:-
Since `.groovy` compiles to `.class` bytecode, parsing the class would give you an `instanceof` `Class`. Now it becomes all JAVA world, only difference, once you get hold of `GroovyObject` after instantiatiation, you play around invoking methods on demand.

Edit: Just so it's contained here:

```
InputStream groovyClassIS = GroovyCompiler.class
     .getResourceAsStream("/org/jboss/loom/tools/groovy/Foo.groovy");

GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader();
Class clazz = gcl.parseClass(groovyClassIS, "SomeClassName.groovy");
Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
IFoo action = (IFoo) obj;
System.out.println( action.foo());
```

and

```
package org.jboss.loom.migrators.mail;

import org.jboss.loom.tools.groovy.IFoo;

public class Foo implements IFoo {
    public String foo(){
        return "Foooooooooo Action!";
    }
}
```