# Jenkins Groovy Postbuild use static file instead of script

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to load an external groovy script into the groovy post build plugin instead of pasting the script content into each job?  We have approximately 200 jobs so updating them all is rather time consuming.  I know that I could write a script to update the config files directly (as in this post: [Add Jenkins Groovy Postbuild step to all jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213693/add-jenkins-groovy-postbuild-step-to-all-jobs)), but these jobs run 24x7 so finding a window when I can restart Jenkins or reload the config is problematic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**:  This is what really solved it for me: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21480

"I am able to do just that by doing the following. Enter these lines in lieu of the script in the "Groovy script" box:"

```
// Delegate to an external script
// The filename must match the class name
import JenkinsPostBuild
def postBuild = new JenkinsPostBuild(manager)
postBuild.run()
```

"Then in the "Additional groovy classpath" box enter the path to that file."

Answer (score 3):

Just put the following in the "Groovy script:" field:

evaluate(new File("... groovy script file name ..."));

Also, you might want to go even further.
What if script name or path changes?
Using [Template plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Project+Plugin) you can create a single "template" job, define call to groovy script (above line) in there, and in all jobs that need it add post-build action called "Use publishers from another project" referencing this template project.

Comment: e.g. script in workspace: ```evaluate(new File(manager.build.workspace.toString() + "/dirinworkspace/scriptname.groovy"))```

Answer (score 1):

We do it in the following fashion.

We have a file `c:\somepath\MyScriptLibClass.groovy` (accessible for Jenkins) which contains code of a groovy class MyScriptLibClass. The class contains a number of functions designed to act like static methods (to be mixed in later).

We include this functions writing the following statement in the beginning of sytem groovy and postbuild groovy steps:

```
[ // include lib scripts
    'MyScriptLibClass'
].each{ this.metaClass.mixin(new GroovyScriptEngine('c:\\somepath').loadScriptByName(it+'.groovy')) }
```

This could look a bit ugly but you need to write it only once for script. You could include more than one script and also use inheritance between library classes.

Here you see that all methods from the library class are mixed in the current script. So if your class looks like:

```
class MyScriptLibClass {
    def setBuildName( String str ){
        binding?.variables['manager'].build.displayName = str
    }
}
```

in Groovy Postbuild you could write just:

```
[ // include lib scripts
    'MyScriptLibClass'
].each{ this.metaClass.mixin(new GroovyScriptEngine('c:\\somepath').loadScriptByName(it+'.groovy')) }

setBuildName( 'My Greatest Build' )
```

and it will change your current build's name.

There are also other ways to load external groovy classes and it is not necessary to use mixing in. For instance you can take a look here [Compiling and using Groovy classes from Java at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902906/compiling-and-using-groovy-classes-from-java-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

How did I solve this:

Create file $JENKINS_HOME/scripts/PostbuildActions.groovy with following content:

```
public class PostbuildActions {
  void setBuildName(Object manager, String str ){
    binding?.variables['manager'].build.displayName = str
  }
}
```

In this case in Groovy Postbuild you could write:

```
File script = new File("${manager.envVars['JENKINS_HOME']}/scripts/PostbuildActions.groovy")
Object actions = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()).parseClass(script).newInstance();

actions.setBuildName(manager, 'My Greatest Build');
```

Comment: manager.envVars throws exceptions for me in groovy postbuild. Have to do ```build = Thread.currentThread().executable``` followed by ```build.getEnvVars()["JENKINS_HOME"]```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have the Groovy script in your Code Repository, and loaded onto the Build / Test Slave in the workspace, then you need to be aware that Groovy Postbuild runs on the Master.

For us, the master is a Unix Server, while the Build/Test Slaves are Windows PCs on the local network. As a result, prior to using the script, we must open a channel from the master to the Slave, and use a [FilePath](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/FilePath.html) to the file.

The following worked for us:

```
// Get an Instance of the Build object, and from there
// the channel from the Master to the Workspace
build = Thread.currentThread().executable
channel = build.workspace.channel;

// Open a FilePath to the script
fp = new FilePath(channel, build.workspace.toString() + "<relative path to the script in Unix notation>")

// Some have suggested that the "Not NULL" check is redundant
// I've kept it for completeness
if(fp != null)
{
    // 'Evaluate' requires a string, so read the file contents to a String
    script = fp.readToString();
    // Execute the script
    evaluate(script);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced with the same task and tried to use @Blaskovicz approach.
Unfortunately it does not work for me, but I find upgraded code [here (Zach Auclair)](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18989?focusedCommentId=269001&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-269001)

Publish here with minor changes:

### postbuild task

```
//imports
import hudson.model.*
import groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader;
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import java.io.File;

// define git file
def postBuildFile = manager.build.getEnvVars()["WORKSPACE"] + "/Jenkins/SimpleTaskPostBuildReporter.GROOVY"
def file = new File(postBuildFile)
// load custom class from file
Class groovy = this.class.classLoader.parseClass(file);
// create custom object
GroovyObject groovyObj = (GroovyObject) groovy.newInstance(manager);
// do report
groovyObj.report();
```

### postbuild class file in git repo (SimpleTaskPostBuildReporter.GROOVY)

```
class SimpleTaskPostBuildReporter {
  def manager

  public SimpleTaskPostBuildReporter(Object manager){
    if(manager == null) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Manager object can't be null")
    }
    this.manager = manager
  }

  public def report() {
    // do work with manager object
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this exactly.

You could try the [Jenkins Job DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) which allows you to rebuild jobs from within jenkins using a Groovy DSL and supports post build groovy steps directly from the [wiki](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-reference)

> Groovy Postbuild
>
> Executes Groovy scripts after a build.
>
> groovyPostBuild(String script, Behavior behavior = Behavior.DoNothing)
>   Arguments:
>
> script The Groovy script to execute after the build. See the plugin's
>   page for details on what can be done. behavior optional. If the script
>   fails, allows you to set mark the build as failed, unstable, or do
>   nothing. The behavior argument uses an enum, which currently has three
>   values: DoNothing, MarkUnstable, and MarkFailed.
>
> Examples:
>
> This example will run a groovy script that prints hello, world and if
>   that fails, it won't affect the build's status:
>
> ```
> groovyPostBuild('println "hello, world"') This example will run a 
>         groovy script, and if that fails will mark the build as failed:
>
> groovyPostBuild('// some groovy script', Behavior.MarkFailed) This example 
>         will run a groovy script, and if that fails will mark the
> ```
>
> build as unstable:
>
> ```
> groovyPostBuild('// some groovy script', Behavior.MarkUnstable) (Since 1.19)
> ```

There is a facility to use a template job (this is the bit I haven't tried) which could be the job itself so you only need to add the post build step. If you don't use a template you need to recode the whole project.

My approach is to have a script to regenerate or create all jobs from scratch just so I don't have to apply the same upgrade multiple times. Regenerated jobs keep their build history

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the following to work (I also posted [on this jira issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18989?focusedCommentId=239142&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-239142)).

### in my postbuild task

```
this.class.classLoader.parseClass("/home/jenkins/GitlabPostbuildReporter.groovy")
GitlabPostbuildReporter.newInstance(manager).report()
```

### in my file on disk at `/home/jenkins/GitlabPostbuildReporter.groovy`

```
class GitlabPostbuildReporter {
  def manager
  public GitlabPostbuildReporter(manager){
    if(manager == null) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Manager object musn't be null")
    }
    this.manager = manager
  }
  public def report() {
    // do work with manager object
  }
}
```