# How to re-use groovy script in Jenkins Groovy Post Build plugin?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have some groovy code which I am planning to re-use in Jenkins Groovy Post Build plugin of multiple jobs. How can I achieve this? Is there a place I can store the script in a global variable and call that in the jobs where ever I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

1. Installed Scriptler plugin for Jenkins and saved the Groovy script in that. Now the script is available in `JENKINS_HOME/scriptler/scripts` directory. This way we can avoid manual step of copying files to Jenkins master.
2. Used the groovy file in Post build:

`def env = manager.build.getEnvironment(manager.listener) evaluate(new File(env['JENKINS_HOME'] + "\\scriptler\\scripts\\GroovyForPostBuild.groovy"))`

Answer (score 2):

You can load any groovy file living on the Jenkins master within the groovy postbuild and execute it.  For example, you could have a special directory on the c drive where all the common scripts live. I'll update my answer later with some code that shows you how to load the script in.

**Update**

Assuming you have a test.groovy file on your C: drive, it should be as simple as the following in Groovy Postbuild:

```
evaluate(new File("C:\\test.groovy"))
```

Please view the comment section of the [Groovy Postbuild](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) for more examples and possibly other ways.

Comment: Than you. This solution helped me half way. Here is the what I did to make it a complete solution:

Comment: I think your comment got truncated as I don't see the solution..  If you want, you can add your solution as another answer and then accept that as the final solution to your problem.. It would probably help others.  If my answer was helpful to you, feel free to up vote it. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a copy of [my answer to this similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43604349/1589770):

If you wish to have the Groovy script in your Code Repository, and loaded onto the Build / Test Slave in the workspace, then you need to be aware that Groovy Postbuild runs on the Master.

For us, the master is a Unix Server, while the Build/Test Slaves are Windows PCs on the local network. As a result, prior to using the script, we must open a channel from the master to the Slave, and use a [FilePath](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/FilePath.html) to the file.

The following worked for us:

```
// Get an Instance of the Build object, and from there
// the channel from the Master to the Workspace
build = Thread.currentThread().executable
channel = build.workspace.channel;

// Open a FilePath to the script
fp = new FilePath(channel, build.workspace.toString() + "<relative path to the script in Unix notation>")

// Some have suggested that the "Not NULL" check is redundant
// I've kept it for completeness
if(fp != null)
{
    // 'Evaluate' requires a string, so read the file contents to a String
    script = fp.readToString();
    // Execute the script
    evaluate(script);
}
```